# What is difference between poke face and triangulate face in 3d modeling

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Can anybody explain what is difference may be it's at geometry level and operation of it and what possibilities are in both tool for better explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poke face is on the left, Triangulate is on the right. Appears that Poke ends up with a vertex in center of the face and Triangulate ends up with just an edge.
[image]